# Ms Sql Stored Procedured select value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**Stored Procedured:**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[StockEnumerationDetailGetFindProduct]

       @StockEnumerationMasterId BIGINT,
       @ProductId BIGINT

    as


    DECLARE @Remaining float
    DECLARE @WarehouseStock float
    DECLARE @WarehouseCode nvarchar(10)


begin

    set @WarehouseCode= 
    (
    Select w.Code  from [dbo].StockEnumerationMaster as SEM
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Warehouses as w on w.[Id]=SEM.WarehouseId
    where
    SEM.Id=@StockEnumerationMasterId)

    set @WarehouseStock=dbo.FncWareHouseStockControl(@WarehouseCode,@ProductId)



    select @WarehouseStock

end
```

Select @WarehouseStock does not work in code side.

**My Code :**

```
 public IList<FormEnumerationDetailModel> StockEnumerationDetailGetFindProduct(long stockEnumerationMasterId, long productId)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Resources.ConnectionString))
            {
                var command = new SqlCommand(Properties.Resources.StockEnumerationDetailGetFindProduct, connection);
                var formEnumerationDetailModel = new List<FormEnumerationDetailModel>();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockEnumerationMasterId", stockEnumerationMasterId);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", productId);
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        formEnumerationDetailModel.Add(new FormEnumerationDetailModel()
                        {
                            Unit = float.Parse(reader["WarehouseStock"].ToString())
                        });
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    return formEnumerationDetailModel;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return new List<FormEnumerationDetailModel>();
                }
            }
            return new List<FormEnumerationDetailModel>();
        }
```

**Exception :**

{"WarehouseStock"}

Why exception just displays me "{"WarehouseStock"}" ?

If i run Stored procedured on ms sql it works.

However if i run stored procedured on code side it gives "{"WarehouseStock"}" exception.

Where i miss exactly ?

**Any help will be appreciated.**

**Thanks.**

Comment: Does `select @WarehouseStock as WarehouseStock` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `select @WarehouseStock` line in the procedure to `select @WarehouseStock as WarehouseStock`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ExecuteReader and looping through the single result, you can use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) when you know the stored proc returns just a single value.

```
connection.Open();
var unit = (float)command.ExecuteScalar();
connection.Close();
formEnumerationDetailModel.Add(new FormEnumerationDetailModel()
         {
             Unit = unit
         });
```